# in akka tutorial, what does the iot supervisor do if it does not interact with other actors?

Tags: akka

I'm going through the [tutorial here](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/typed/guide/tutorial_2.html), and am seeing that the `create` method on IotSupervisor is called and the result passed to `ActorSystem` in the root of the application. However, I was wondering why would this unused actor be used instead of `DeviceManager`, which is the top-most actor that interacts with its child actors.

Answer (score 0):

Because both `DeviceManager` and `DashboardManager` will be IotSupervisor's children according to the diagram. That's why the application needs an entry point which lives in a higher level than `DeviceManager`.

Find the diagram below, I copy it from the exact tutorial link.

[image]

Comment: at the end of the tutorial, there is a disconnect between the IoTSupervisor and the DeviceManager.  Also, per this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62868001/is-it-ever-ok-to-dispatch-a-child-actor-directly-or-must-all-messages-be-passed?noredirect=1#comment111173828_62868001 , it looks like messages should not be passed from the root to the child actors but rather to the child directly.

Comment: Yah you don't want to pass messages from the root to the child, instead the message should be sent to the child directly. The root actor is there not for "traffic routing" purpose, instead, it is for "supervision" purposes: It supervises both DeviceManager and DashboardManager. If any of the 2 actors stopped due to whatever reason, the supervisor is responsible for either restarting its child or shut down the whole actor system, or something else.

Comment: Also, again, you have DashboardManager. If you don't specify an IoTSupervisor, how would you initialize the DashboardManager? Do you specify that under DeviceManager? This doesn't seem ideal because Device and Dashboard are separate concepts.

Comment: awesome. that really helps clarify. When I tried to reach the child actor by creating an ActorRef from within the ActorSystem logic, I get this error: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: cannot create top-level actor [dev-mgr] from the outside on ActorSystem with custom user guardian`.  unfortunately, I wasn't able to find any examples or tutorials that follow a multi-level flow being called from the top level class where the ActorSystem lives.

Comment: i think that's another question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62868001/is-it-ever-ok-to-dispatch-a-child-actor-directly-or-must-all-messages-be-passed. We shall close up this question and move the discussion there.

Comment: @reactor Can you adopt the answer please if it answers your question?